# Headless chrome print to pdf return errors and stuck forever

Tags: google-chrome, headless, google-chrome-headless, headless-browser

I"m trying to print a page to pdf.

it's a pretty big page. I used the following command to generate it

```
/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --headless --enable-logging=stderr --v=99 --run-all-compositor-stages-before-draw --disable-gpu --print-to-pdf=test-file-339.pdf  https://master-7rqtwti-wnjvz3rv66pcy.eu-5.platformsh.site/en/msf_pdf/book/339\?no_lang
```

but after a couple of line logs, it starts to stick on unfinished logs.

```
[0524/233210.306204:VERBOSE1:media_stream_manager.cc(870)] MSM::OnSpeedLimitChange({this=0x20003fb400}, {new_limit=97})
[0524/233210.413012:VERBOSE1:media_stream_manager.cc(870)] MSM::OnSpeedLimitChange({this=0x20003fb400}, {new_limit=95})
[0524/233210.568006:VERBOSE1:media_stream_manager.cc(870)] MSM::OnSpeedLimitChange({this=0x20003fb400}, {new_limit=93})
[0524/233210.715803:VERBOSE1:media_stream_manager.cc(870)] MSM::OnSpeedLimitChange({this=0x20003fb400}, {new_limit=91})
[0524/233210.803434:VERBOSE1:media_stream_manager.cc(870)] MSM::OnSpeedLimitChange({this=0x20003fb400}, {new_limit=89})
[0524/233211.153660:VERBOSE1:media_stream_manager.cc(870)] MSM::OnSpeedLimitChange({this=0x20003fb400}, {new_limit=87})
[0524/233212.135127:VERBOSE1:media_stream_manager.cc(870)] MSM::OnSpeedLimitChange({this=0x20003fb400}, {new_limit=85})
[0524/233214.447553:VERBOSE1:media_stream_manager.cc(870)] MSM::OnSpeedLimitChange({this=0x20003fb400}, {new_limit=82})
[0524/233214.668568:VERBOSE1:media_stream_manager.cc(870)] MSM::OnSpeedLimitChange({this=0x20003fb400}, {new_limit=80})
[0524/233216.502354:VERBOSE1:media_stream_manager.cc(870)] MSM::OnSpeedLimitChange({this=0x20003fb400}, {new_limit=82})
[0524/233216.916280:VERBOSE1:media_stream_manager.cc(870)] MSM::OnSpeedLimitChange({this=0x20003fb400}, {new_limit=85})
[0524/233217.403114:VERBOSE1:media_stream_manager.cc(870)] MSM::OnSpeedLimitChange({this=0x20003fb400}, {new_limit=87})
[0524/233217.619494:VERBOSE1:media_stream_manager.cc(870)] MSM::OnSpeedLimitChange({this=0x20003fb400}, {new_limit=85})
[0524/233217.723483:VERBOSE1:media_stream_manager.cc(870)] MSM::OnSpeedLimitChange({this=0x20003fb400}, {new_limit=82})
[0524/233217.846369:VERBOSE1:media_stream_manager.cc(870)] MSM::OnSpeedLimitChange({this=0x20003fb400}, {new_limit=80})
[0524/233218.022488:VERBOSE1:media_stream_manager.cc(870)] MSM::OnSpeedLimitChange({this=0x20003fb400}, {new_limit=78})
[0524/233218.763335:VERBOSE1:media_stream_manager.cc(870)] MSM::OnSpeedLimitChange({this=0x20003fb400}, {new_limit=80})
[0524/233219.594588:VERBOSE1:media_stream_manager.cc(870)] MSM::OnSpeedLimitChange({this=0x20003fb400}, {new_limit=82})
[0524/233220.020179:VERBOSE1:media_stream_manager.cc(870)] MSM::OnSpeedLimitChange({this=0x20003fb400}, {new_limit=85})
[0524/233220.316092:VERBOSE1:media_stream_manager.cc(870)] MSM::OnSpeedLimitChange({this=0x20003fb400}, {new_limit=87})
[0524/233220.937315:VERBOSE1:media_stream_manager.cc(870)] MSM::OnSpeedLimitChange({this=0x20003fb400}, {new_limit=85})
[0524/233221.077081:VERBOSE1:media_stream_manager.cc(870)] MSM::OnSpeedLimitChange({this=0x20003fb400}, {new_limit=82})
[0524/233221.259559:VERBOSE1:media_stream_manager.cc(870)] MSM::OnSpeedLimitChange({this=0x20003fb400}, {new_limit=80})
[0524/233221.886193:VERBOSE1:media_stream_manager.cc(870)] MSM::OnSpeedLimitChange({this=0x20003fb400}, {new_limit=82})
[0524/233222.176253:VERBOSE1:media_stream_manager.cc(870)] MSM::OnSpeedLimitChange({this=0x20003fb400}, {new_limit=85})
[0524/233223.523138:VERBOSE1:media_stream_manager.cc(870)] MSM::OnSpeedLimitChange({this=0x20003fb400}, {new_limit=87})
[0524/233223.680410:VERBOSE1:media_stream_manager.cc(870)] MSM::OnSpeedLimitChange({this=0x20003fb400}, {new_limit=89})
[0524/233223.852440:VERBOSE1:media_stream_manager.cc(870)] MSM::OnSpeedLimitChange({this=0x20003fb400}, {new_limit=91})
[0524/233224.042596:VERBOSE1:media_stream_manager.cc(870)] MSM::OnSpeedLimitChange({this=0x20003fb400}, {new_limit=93})
[0524/233224.227405:VERBOSE1:media_stream_manager.cc(870)] MSM::OnSpeedLimitChange({this=0x20003fb400}, {new_limit=95})
[0524/233224.397228:VERBOSE1:media_stream_manager.cc(870)] MSM::OnSpeedLimitChange({this=0x20003fb400}, {new_limit=97})
[0524/233224.524395:VERBOSE1:media_stream_manager.cc(870)] MSM::OnSpeedLimitChange({this=0x20003fb400}, {new_limit=100})
[0524/233430.673450:VERBOSE1:media_stream_manager.cc(870)] MSM::OnSpeedLimitChange({this=0x20003fb400}, {new_limit=97})
[0524/233430.787732:VERBOSE1:media_stream_manager.cc(870)] MSM::OnSpeedLimitChange({this=0x20003fb400}, {new_limit=95})
[0524/233430.887171:VERBOSE1:media_stream_manager.cc(870)] MSM::OnSpeedLimitChange({this=0x20003fb400}, {new_limit=93})
[0524/233430.996555:VERBOSE1:media_stream_manager.cc(870)] MSM::OnSpeedLimitChange({this=0x20003fb400}, {new_limit=91})
[0524/233431.042080:VERBOSE1:media_stream_manager.cc(870)] MSM::OnSpeedLimitChange({this=0x20003fb400}, {new_limit=89})
[0524/233431.141115:VERBOSE1:media_stream_manager.cc(870)] MSM::OnSpeedLimitChange({this=0x20003fb400}, {new_limit=87})
[0524/233431.226114:VERBOSE1:media_stream_manager.cc(870)] MSM::OnSpeedLimitChange({this=0x20003fb400}, {new_limit=85})
[0524/233431.328022:VERBOSE1:media_stream_manager.cc(870)] MSM::OnSpeedLimitChange({this=0x20003fb400}, {new_limit=82})
[0524/233431.455741:VERBOSE1:media_stream_manager.cc(870)] MSM::OnSpeedLimitChange({this=0x20003fb400}, {new_limit=80})
[0524/233431.601629:VERBOSE1:media_stream_manager.cc(870)] MSM::OnSpeedLimitChange({this=0x20003fb400}, {new_limit=78})
[0524/233431.795468:VERBOSE1:media_stream_manager.cc(870)] MSM::OnSpeedLimitChange({this=0x20003fb400}, {new_limit=76})
[0524/233431.980355:VERBOSE1:media_stream_manager.cc(870)] MSM::OnSpeedLimitChange({this=0x20003fb400}, {new_limit=74})
[0524/233432.312146:VERBOSE1:media_stream_manager.cc(870)] MSM::OnSpeedLimitChange({this=0x20003fb400}, {new_limit=72})
[0524/233433.968318:VERBOSE1:media_stream_manager.cc(870)] MSM::OnSpeedLimitChange({this=0x20003fb400}, {new_limit=74})
[0524/233434.436336:VERBOSE1:media_stream_manager.cc(870)] MSM::OnSpeedLimitChange({this=0x20003fb400}, {new_limit=76})
[0524/233434.584234:VERBOSE1:media_stream_manager.cc(870)] MSM::OnSpeedLimitChange({this=0x20003fb400}, {new_limit=78})
[0524/233434.716277:VERBOSE1:media_stream_manager.cc(870)] MSM::OnSpeedLimitChange({this=0x20003fb400}, {new_limit=80})
[0524/233434.959281:VERBOSE1:media_stream_manager.cc(870)] MSM::OnSpeedLimitChange({this=0x20003fb400}, {new_limit=82})
[0524/233435.218106:VERBOSE1:media_stream_manager.cc(870)] MSM::OnSpeedLimitChange({this=0x20003fb400}, {new_limit=85})
[0524/233435.383915:VERBOSE1:media_stream_manager.cc(870)] MSM::OnSpeedLimitChange({this=0x20003fb400}, {new_limit=87})
[0524/233435.513166:VERBOSE1:media_stream_manager.cc(870)] MSM::OnSpeedLimitChange({this=0x20003fb400}, {new_limit=89})
[0524/233435.675487:VERBOSE1:media_stream_manager.cc(870)] MSM::OnSpeedLimitChange({this=0x20003fb400}, {new_limit=91})
[0524/233435.911322:VERBOSE1:media_stream_manager.cc(870)] MSM::OnSpeedLimitChange({this=0x20003fb400}, {new_limit=93})
[0524/233436.050401:VERBOSE1:media_stream_manager.cc(870)] MSM::OnSpeedLimitChange({this=0x20003fb400}, {new_limit=95})
[0524/233436.179286:VERBOSE1:media_stream_manager.cc(870)] MSM::OnSpeedLimitChange({this=0x20003fb400}, {new_limit=97})
[0524/233436.336253:VERBOSE1:media_stream_manager.cc(870)] MSM::OnSpeedLimitChange({this=0x20003fb400}, {new_limit=100})
```

this is the url of the page : [https://master-7rqtwti-wnjvz3rv66pcy.eu-5.platformsh.site/en/msf_pdf/book/33\?no_lang](https://master-7rqtwti-wnjvz3rv66pcy.eu-5.platformsh.site/en/msf_pdf/book/33%5C?no_lang)
it could be something is wrong with the page which cause issue in chrome.

I haven't found any related issue on the net and I have no idea what this means and how can I resolve this.

the strange thing is that it's working for other pages in the same but for this page it's not working.

any thought could be helpful.

additionally I noticed this issue is happening https://superuser.com/q/1722805/134343
so it might be something is wrong with chrome itself.

Comment: @KJ that pdf generated by chrome headless ;)

Answer (score 0):

Just for record for people have the same issue:

the problem was in my DOM , there was a borken DOM tag that casue this issue. check your DOM and be sure all is ok with that.